# Outlook 2010 - Attach room image(s) to room resource

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, resources

We are trying to migrate off of a paid meeting/room software product to using outlook for rooms/meetings. Pretty much everything seems to work how we want it including adding room attributes. Where I'm struggling is on our current meeting room software we have a picture of the room and a floor plan of floor/building the room is on. The pictures are very helpful and needed. Is there any way to add an attachment to a room resource? Or is there a way to add a hyperlink somewhere to the room resource's properties? I tried putting html and just a link in the notes section of the room but it just displays text. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: "... it just displays text.", please clarify where exactly it displays text.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  Adding html to the notes section of a room's prperties hoping it would display as HTML.  For instance this, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5K0hZRXSQVDeU1sYzNmOXBBUTg/edit?usp=sharing